# Cassandra C# Driver - SELECT Statement Execution Slow

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra

I'm running a 3-node Cassandra 3.0.0 cluster running on AWS EC2 i3.large instances and I've been playing around with using the C# driver for Cassandra.  Executing the following query (which is very simple) takes approximately 300 ms (to scan the single partition and return the top 100 rows).

`var rs = session.Execute("SELECT col1, col6, col7 FROM breadcrumbs WHERE col1='samplepk' LIMIT 100;");`

My data model is:

Column 1 = a 13-character string

Column 2 = a 23-character string

Column 3 = a date/time timestamp

Column 4 = a 4-digit integer

Column 5 = a 3 digit integer

Column 6 = a latitude value

Column 7 = a longitude value

Column 8 = a 15-digit double

Column 9 = a 15-digit double

I defined my primary key as Col1, col2.

My C# driver code is as follows:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint(~~~~~IP Here~~~~).Build();
        ISession session = cluster.Connect(~~~keyspacename~~~);
        long ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        var rs = session.Execute("SELECT col2, col6, col7 FROM breadcrumbs WHERE partitionkey=~targetkey~ LIMIT 100;");
        Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now.Ticks - ticks)/Math.Pow(10,4)+" ms");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Is that abnormally slow or are my expectations too high?  If it is slow, does anyone have any ideas about what's causing it?

If I forgot to provide any pertinent details, please leave a comment :) .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your data model?  It's hard to know exactly what's slow without seeing your table structure.

Comment: And my 14 year old loved your username.  LOL.

Comment: Can you try to execute same query using cqlsh localy from one of the servers and check the time?

Comment: You can enable tracing on CQLSH to see what's going on: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/tracing_r.html and you can enable logging on the driver side: http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.2/faq/#how-can-i-enable-logging-in-the-driver

Comment: @Aaron I updated the original post with my data model.  Is that enough detail about the model?

Comment: Do you ever delete anything from this table?  And replace your column definitions with the output of `desc table breadcrumbs`.

Comment: @Aaron I deleted the entire contents of the table (approx 5M rows) using TRUNCATE when I first loaded the data because an error was thrown saying that one of the SSTables was corrupted.  Then, I reloaded the data.  Could the tombstones be the problem?

Comment: @nevsv running the query through cqlsh took approx 8 ms.  Same query run through the driver took 295 ms.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like you are doing something goofy in your C# code.

Comment: My C# code is executing the exact same query.  I'll post the code above.

Comment: Try to run several (hundreds) of requests after cluster object creation in C#. It can be just that initialization part of the driver takes to much time.

Comment: @nevsv that seemed to be the main problem.  Runtime drops down to approx 60ms.  Is there any way to make it faster? :)

Comment: Sure :). Download source code of C# driver and make it faster :). If you don't want to, try to use token aware policy, and start working with async requests and parallel executions. I'm not C# expert, and i don't sure you can make c# driver run much faster, but to ensure what part of your 60ms requests are due to network, try to run your example code using any other language that has Cassandra drivers. With python in AWS infrastructure we got around ~(15-30ms) in same VPC.

Comment: @nevsv I tested the NodeJS driver and it gets near-identical times (64 ms to query an empty partition on both drivers).  Is the Python driver any better?  Are there any driver settings to tune?

Comment: Do you use token aware policy(driver settings)? Do your servers are in the same VPC with Cassandra? Also try to upgrade i3large to i3xlarge and do the tests, and see if there's any difference.

Comment: @nevsv It's most likely network latency as I'm running my node server on my local machine.  I deployed another cluster in a AWS region that's physically closer to me and the time to query an empty partition halved.

Comment: Ok, good to hear.